# How to increase query execution time in php

Tags: php

My site is a messaging site ,There users can send messages to individual and group messages,In group there are about large number of people, if users send to message to group, the server time outs and  the site got hang for 2 hrs. Any method to solve these problem.

Comment: What causes this two hour hang? I can see PHP killing your script for exceeding cpu and/or execution time limits, but it doesn't impose a 2hour cooldown. That'd be something your hosting provider is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For maximum execution time try:

`set_time_limit(0);`

Also try to optimize your query. And use sleep in between each interval of 50 or 100 slots.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use **cronjob**.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

also you can change it using

> void set_time_limit ( int $seconds )

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

or change max_execution_time in ini file

http://www.imagedia.com/2009/09/changing-php-ini-for-longer-execution-time/

Answer (score 1):

I would like to know whether your messaging system that handles group messages inside Your DB(i.e. receivers read messages inside your system as facebook) or sending emails out to a group? If it is emails to a group, we can set a cron job or integrate a third mailing system that could resolve your issue. If the messaging is done internally which is stored in your own DB, there is no reason to hang the system for 2 hours unless you designed your database badly or using a faulty logic. It will be better if you could share me the Table structure for keeping the messages and the current logic you used to share it between the group users.

Comment: its a messaging system to send messages to cellphones in us only, for messaging send grid API is used. Users can type the message and select group from drop down list to send message.

Comment: Oh okay.. if that is the case, you should change your messaging logic. Instead of sending messages from front end, You have set a cron job that utilizes the API to send messages.. You can schedule the cron job for to run on every one minute or five minutes and it will check the db for the messages in queue and send it instantly. In the front end, when someone sends a message, just place it in the db for the cron job to access and send. 

Thus the end user do not need to wait for something that can be handled in the backend.